# PHP 5.3: mysqli_multi_query and "commands out of sync" errors

Tags: php, mysqli

When I use mysqli_multi_query() with a mass INSERT query, then after the query has run do another query using mysqli_query('SELECT...'), I get "commands out of sync" errors. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to call [mysqli_use_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php) (or [mysqli_store_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php)) after a `mysqli_multi_query()` call.

Lower level documentation about this error: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_next_result($db) , after freeing the result set if any . This alone would fix the out of sync issues.